# C# How to launch a clickonce winforms project from another clickonce winforms project in debug mode

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I have a solution with two winforms project. Project A is used to launch multiple copies of project B, each with different args.

It works fine if I build project B and launch the exe from project A.  Problem is I want to be able to step through project B once it has been launched by project A so that I can debug issues with the args being passed.

How do I set up the projects so that I can pass in the args and step through from project A to project B?

Comment: I didn't :(  I couldn't make them work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Debugger.Launch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Write this to Project B's entry point and run Project A.

> Debugger.Launch Method ()
>
> Launches and attaches a debugger to the process.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio lets you to set startup options like command-line arguments for application debugging.

As an option you can set the project you want to debug as startup project and then using `Properties > Debug > Command line arguments` set desired command-line arguments and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug as usual.

> The Command line arguments property specifies command-line arguments
>   to be called when launching the application.

For more information, take a look at:
[How to: Set Start Options for Application Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ktzfy9w(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I tested the solution and it works properly. It doesn't dependent to using or not using click once. It just set a command line argument for your application in debug mode. So if you gave it another try, let me know if you had any question about applying the solution or let me know if you find it useful.